# Writing a sequence of numbers like: 1 22 333 4444 55555

Tags: c++

Okay so, I have to write a c++ program that reads a number and then proceeds to write every number up until the number that we read the same amount of times as its value. I have absolutely no idea how to explain this or what to search for so I'm hoping you understand what I need and can help me.

Basically, if we cin >> 5, the output should be `1 22 333 4444 55555`. I have a feeling this is extremely easy but nothing crosses my mind right now. I tried with 2 for statements but I can't seem to get it right.

This is my attempt:

```
int main () 
{ 
   int i,j,n;
   cout<<"n=";cin>>n;
   for (i=n;i>=1;i--) 
   { 
      for (j=1;j<=i;j++) 
      { 
         cout << i; 
      } 
      cout<<" ";
   } 
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Let's see your code and we will help you finish it

Comment: Yes it should be possible with 2 for loops. Edit your question to include your attempt and we will guide you from there

Comment: Hint: One `for` loop inside another.

Comment: Try to write a function called `writeRepeatedNumber(int n)`

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  int a;
  std::cin>>a;
  for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
      std::cout<<i;
    std::cout<<"  ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I shouldn't have given this code to OP before his minimal effort to solve, but somehow I felt pity :P

Comment: I don't know how to use the code editor here and paste my code. The code I had written was going 55555 4444 333 22 1 instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Boann I think you guys should nominate me for next Nobel prize for the invention of the universal cure ;)

Comment: No you didn't cause too much trouble, you just forgot to include your code in your question and that is it. Had you done that, there would not be so many down votes. Since I know you did attempt to code it, from the comments, I have voted to reopen your question. There is nothing wrong with it other than that. Edit your question and put the code that you had yourself.

Comment: Yes, if you edit in your attempt I will vote to reopen. There is an edit button just below the question. Paste your code, then select it and hit the button marked `{}` to format it.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. At the very least, the code should be documented.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Please enter a number";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
        cout<<i;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy.

- use cout to prompt for a number
- use cin to read a number
- you need an inner loop to print the copies of the digit, follow with a space
- you need an outer loop to loop from 1 to the number, follow with a newline (endline)

Here is the answer,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int upto, ndx, cdx;
    cout<<"number=";
    cin>>upto;
    for(ndx=1;ndx<=upto;++ndx)
    {
        for(cdx=1;cdx<=ndx;++cdx)
            cout<<ndx;
        cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j,n=5;
clrscr();  
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
      {
      cout<<i;
      }
    cout<<endl;
  }
getch();
}
```

Comment: Add details to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i,j;  //declaring two variables I,j.

  for (i=1; i<10; i++)  //loop over the variable i so it variates from 1 to 10.
  {
      for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)  //create an other loop for a variable j to loop over again and o/p value of i
      {
          cout <<i;  //writes the value of i directly from i and also due to the loop over j.
      }
      cout<<endl;  //manipulator to analyze the result easily.
  }
  return (0);
}
```